# is there a way to output specific part of array depending on the user's country?

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce, handlebarshelper, stencil-component

I'm trying to get values of name: and value: depending on the user's country code. So example users location is 'DE' it should output:

**TRS_TITLE_DE**

**Harry Potter Chamber Of Secrets I Hard Back Case Compatible With Apple iPhone 12**

*This is the array:*

```
{
          "id":3,
          "name":"TRS_TITLE_DE",
          "value":"Harry Potter Chamber Of Secrets I Hard Back Case Compatible With Apple iPhone 12"
       },
       {
          "id":4,
          "name":"TRS_TITLE_FR",
          "value":"Harry Potter Chamber Of Secrets I Hard Back Case Compatible With Apple iPhone 12"
       },
       {
          "id":5,
          "name":"TRS_TITLE_IT",
          "value":"Harry Potter Chamber Of Secrets I Hard Back Case Compatible With Apple iPhone 12"
       },
       {
          "id":6,
          "name":"TRS_TITLE_US",
          "value":"Harry Potter Chamber Of Secrets I Hard Back Case Compatible With Apple iPhone 12"
       },
```

This is what I have tried:

```
{{#if settings.country_code "==" "DE"}}
  <h1>
    {{itemAt product.custom_fields 2}}    
  </h1>      
{{else}}
    <h1>It's not there</h1>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: It is possible, but it might make more sense to use an object instead of an array so that you can do a lookup like `title[countryCode]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have put the country codes into the custom fields exactly as they would display in the settings, the following should do the trick:

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
    {{#contains name ../settings.country_code}}
        <h1>{{{value}}}</h1>
    {{/contains}}
{{/each}}
```